# OPA create chat throws Uncaught exception

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-errors, opa

After installation, when checked `$opa --version`, it works and shows 1.2.0. But just after that when I typed in `$opa create chat` as shown in document, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught exception : ReferenceError: BslString_char_at is not defined
ReferenceError: BslString_char_at is not defined
    at __v2_next_ec6de8cf (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.opx/main.js:2107:124)
    at __v1_an_aux2_f2f00d5f (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.rpc.core.opx/main.js:1510:132)
    at ___to_text_in_js_ll_f2f00d5f (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.rpc.core.opx/main.js:1518:89)
    at /usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.rpc.core.opx/main.js:2312:60
    at global.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/opabsl.opp/node_modules/opa-js-runtime-cps/main.js:22:49)
    at global.execute1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/opabsl.opp/node_modules/opa-js-runtime-cps/main.js:23:50)
    at global.loop_schedule (/usr/lib/node_modules/opabsl.opp/node_modules/opa-js-runtime-cps/main.js:38:339)
    at global.BslCps_topwait (/usr/lib/node_modules/opabsl.opp/opabslNodeJsPackage.js:958:104)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.xhtml.opx/main.js:911:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

/usr/lib/node_modules/opabsl.opp/opabslNodeJsPackage.js:959
throw new (global.Error)("Your toplevel contains value which can't be synchron
      ^
Error: Your toplevel contains value which can't be synchronously computed
    at global.BslCps_topwait (/usr/lib/node_modules/opabsl.opp/opabslNodeJsPackage.js:959:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.xhtml.opx/main.js:911:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.web.request.opx/main.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
I tried installing and building from source, but still the same issue. Being new to linux as well, not sure how can i solve this. Looks like this is an issue in C++ STL code, but specific function for which it is complaining:

> BslString_char_at is not defined

I am not able to find at internet, not sure form where to pull in and place it.

Your help will be highly appreciated. I do feel that OPA must have a great future and I am yet to get on board.

Thanks,
Abhijit

Comment: Is this the `opa` CLI from Open Policy Agent, or for the Opa framework language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo opa create chat`

works for me

Comment: Thanks. this works for me too and got me get started. Infact all execution of OPA programs also needs commands preceded by "sudo".